# Rearranging columns on a MATLAB matrix in a particular way

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I am working on a MATLAB code that builds a column matrix B from odd-numbered columns of matrix A

[image]

My (messy) code for it is

```
A = rand(5,10);

i = 1
ii = 1
while i <= size(A,2)
    if mod(i+1,2)==0
        B(1:size(A,1),ii) = A(:,i)
        ii = ii + 1
    i = i+1
    end
    i = i + 1
end
```

(which selects the columns but doesn't put everything in a single column, as it should) 
Can someone help me do the same in a simpler way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one *less-messy* way by simply column-indexing with a stepsize of `2` starting from the first column and then reshaping into desired column vector -

```
reshape(A(:,1:2:end),[],1)
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     1     5     9    13    17
     2     6    10    14    18
     3     7    11    15    19
     4     8    12    16    20
>> reshape(A(:,1:2:end),[],1)
ans =
     1
     2
     3
     4
     9
    10
    11
    12
    17
    18
    19
    20
```

Answer (score 2):

Code is given below with respect to your example;

```
A = rand(5,10)
t = A(:,1)'
for R =3: 2: length(A)
    t = [t A(:,R)']
end

Result = t.';
```

Comment: Having a matrix which grows with each loop is bad practise and [should be avoided using pre-allocation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html), also you should use `.'` for transpose, not `'` which is the complex conjugate transpose.

Comment: I know, I'm not saying your solution doesn't *work*, I was trying to help you learn some best practises. In a context where you're trying to educate others, it's always good to try and set the best example possible.